# Android: При добавлении MapKit — SDK Яндекс.Карт сильно увеличивается размер приложения

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Всем привет. С google картами мое приложение имеет размер 5 мегабайт, когда добавляю yandex карты - 40 мегабайт. Что мне с этим делать? Очень нужны yandex карты, почему добавляется такой размер и как этого избежать?

Answer (score 0):

Если я верно понял по вашему профилю, речь об Android (но лучше было бы поставить тег).

Во-первых, вы можете использовать **lite-версию MapKit'a** с ограниченным функционалом.

Во вторых, размер билда можно уменьшить, если использовать APK split — в aar-файле содержится 4 версии библиотек (arm64, armv7, x86, i686), и если вы его рассплитите, то сможете выбрать только нужную версию.